# Python: Range for loop. Do something different every 5

Tags: python, nuke

I am writing a script for Nuke to arrange selected nodes in a grid. Every node has x and y coordinates. This script alters those coordinates. I would like to have the grid have a horizontal length of 5 and then start a new line. I have this written in a range loop. The range is determined by the number of selected nodes. I have multiple if statements that drop the nodes to a new line. My question is if there is a way to clean up the if statements to be less literal and not have to be reiterated every 5 times. Here is the script:

```
list = []
for s in nuke.selectedNodes():
    n = s['name'].value()
    list.append(n)
names = iter(list)

c = len(nuke.selectedNodes())

for i in range(c):

    xNumber = i*200
    yNumber = 0 

    n = i+1

    if n > 5:
        xNumber =  (i-5)*200
        yNumber = 200
    if n > 10: 
        xNumber = (i-10) *200
        yNumber = 400
    if n > 15:
        xNumber =  (i-15)*200
        yNumber = 600
    if n > 20: 
        xNumber = (i-20)*200
        yNumber = 800
    if n > 25:
        xNumber =  (i-25)*200
        yNumber = 1000
    if n > 30: 
        xNumber = (i-30) *200
        yNumber = 1200
    if n > 35:
        xNumber =  (i-35)*200
        yNumber = 1400
    if n > 40: 
        xNumber = (i-40)*200
        yNumber = 1600
    if n > 45:
        xNumber =  (i-45)*200
        yNumber = 1800
    if n > 50: 
        xNumber = (i-50)*200
        yNumber = 2000
    if n > 55:
        xNumber =  (i-55)*200
        yNumber = 2200
    if n > 60: 
        xNumber = (i-60) *200
        yNumber = 2400
    if n > 65:
        xNumber =  (i-65)*200
        yNumber = 2600
    if n > 70: 
        xNumber = (i-70)*200
        yNumber = 2800
    if n > 75:
        xNumber =  (i-75)*200
        yNumber = 3000
    if n > 80: 
        xNumber = (i-80) *200
        yNumber = 3200
    if n > 85:
        xNumber =  (i-85)*200
        yNumber = 3400
    if n > 90: 
        xNumber = (i-90)*200
        yNumber = 3600
    if n > 95:
        xNumber =  (i-95)*200
        yNumber = 3800
    if n > 100: 
        xNumber = (i-100)*200
        yNumber = 4000

    NodeName = next(names)

    nuke.toNode(NodeName)['xpos'].setValue(xNumber)
    nuke.toNode(NodeName)['ypos'].setValue(yNumber)
```

The script works, I just feel like there should be a cleaner way to write this.

Comment: If your script already works, you might want to check [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is, even because, for `n > 100`, your code will execute literally every block inside the `if` statements.

Anyway, your `xNumber` and `yNumber` values seem to be simple functions of `n`. So what about:

```
import math

factor = math.floor(n/5)
xNumber = (i - (factor * 5)) * 200
yNumber = factor * 200
```

Comment: You meant "for n < 100" didn't you ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Nope. If `n > 100`, then it's also true that `n > 5`, `n > 10` etc. As OP used a sequence of `if` instead of `elif`, an `n` greater than 100 will make all conditions true.

Comment: Thank you. This is much cleaner. But it only works for the first 5 nodes. Once the 6th iteration hits, the results are odd and don't fit in a grid. One of the reasons I did all the statements (albeit if and not elif, as I should have) Is so that I could start a new line. I wasn't sure how else to write it other than to force the y to increase by 200 every 5 iterations. and start the x over at 0. In my original code, the x value never exceeds 800. It's always between 0-800, by increments of 200.

Comment: Try to print these values in every iteration and post the ones of the 6th iteration please. This will help us track the problem down.

Comment: `for i in range(9):
 
    n = i+1

    factor = (n/5)
    xNumber = (i - (factor * 5)) * 200
    yNumber = factor * 200

    print xNumber
    print yNumber

# Result: 
0 0
200 0
400 0
600 0
-200 200
0 200
200 200
400 200
600 200`

I did a range of 9 just for demonstration purposes

Comment: `factor = math.floor(n/5)`, not `factor = (n/5)`.

Comment: I don't need floats in this case. Integers are fine.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is tested and working. See the code comments for details. Also let me know if this resolves your problem.

```
list = []
for s in nuke.selectedNodes():
    n = s['name'].value()
    list.append(n)
names = iter(list)

numSelectedNodes = len(nuke.selectedNodes())

#variables. You only need to change following parameters
numberOfColums = 5
xMult= 200
yMult= 40

#numberOfRows = numSelectedNodes/numberOfColums
#reminder = numSelectedNodes%numberOfColums
#if (reminder>0):
#   numberOfRows += 1

# adding 1 as the following will save you above 3 lines of code.
numberOfRows = (numSelectedNodes/numberOfColums)+1


def setPos(xValue,yValue):
    nodeName = next(names)
    nuke.toNode(nodeName)['xpos'].setValue(xValue)
    nuke.toNode(nodeName)['ypos'].setValue(yValue)

i = 0
while (i<numSelectedNodes):

    for j in range(numberOfRows):
        stepMult = j*numberOfColums
        for k in range(numberOfColums):
            xNumber =  (i-stepMult)*xMult
            yNumber = yMult * stepMult
            setPos(xNumber,yNumber)
            i += 1 #  shorthand for i = i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all of the conditional statements using this simple math. It assumes i is not necessarily an integer (depending on your python version)

```
list = []
for s in nuke.selectedNodes():
    n = s['name'].value()
    list.append(n)
names = iter(list)

c = len(nuke.selectedNodes())

for i in range(c):    
    if i <= 100:
        xNumber = ( i - ( ( (int) i ) / 5 ) * 5 ) * 200
        yNumber = ( ( (int) i ) / 5 ) * 200
    else:
        xNumber = (i-100)*200
        yNumber = 4000

    NodeName = next(names)

    nuke.toNode(NodeName)['xpos'].setValue(xNumber)
    nuke.toNode(NodeName)['ypos'].setValue(yNumber)
```